# How to disable password prompt for FileVault-protected secondary macOS?

Tags: macos, password, filevault, dual-boot

I have a dual-boot setup with two macOS Catalina systems, each protected with FileVault.

No system shall store the credentials to unlock the other one to protect them against each other and keep things separate.

However, macOS will always ask for a password to unlock the respective other system's disks after booting up.

Is there a way to disable this prompt without storing the passwords in the keychain?

I tried adding an entry to /etc/fstab with the volume UUID and options `rw,noauto` but that didn't help.

Comment: i've always used `UUID=[uuid] none hfs rw,noauto` which seems to work for me, but I have to admit I have no idea how to actually break down that syntax, it's copy/paste.

Comment: The format is the same as for other UNIX-like systems, but it seems to have no effect on the prompt

Comment: idk whether this is a Catalina 'thing' or a FileVault 'thing' [as I have neither] but it's what I use to prevent other OS drives being mounted, macOS & boot camp. Some of the ones I have listed don't specify `hfs` or indeed any file system [again, I don't actually know how the syntax works, so my efforts are mainly guesswork]